# React useRef: Must I use multiple useRef for multiple fields in a form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with 50-200 text field (number) entries.

I want to use an imported object to create a form, where the user may change values in the form, and submit all values in the form with a single click.

I can do

```
const hamsterObject = {
  key1: useRef("data1"),
  key2: useRef("data2"),
}
...
<input type="text" ref = {key1} />
<input type="text" ref = {key2} />
```

But I feel the code is a little clunky if I do it that way.  I'd like to do something like

```
const hamsterObject2 = useRef(
{
  key1: "data1",
  key2: "data2"
})
<input type="text" ref={hamsterObject.current.value.key1}
```

But as I understand it, when I use ref={aReference}, aReference itself has to be useRef.  I can't reference properties of aReference; I must use aReference itself.  So I would have to do it with aReference, not aReference.current.value.key1.

Do I just need to go ahead and create loads of useRefs; is that the accepted method?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use React refs at all? What are the refs for? Are the inputs dynamic, e.g. rendered from an array or similar? I think we need a bit more context here for the use case. Can you [edit] to provide a more accurate [mcve] of the code you are working with?

Comment: can you just use `useState`, or is there a specific reason for using `ref`?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at react hook forms, it will make your life 100x easier.
https://www.react-hook-form.com/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Did you mean to instead leave it as a comment as a suggestion to the OP?